# Web app to monitor the status of Yahoo Mail, Twitter and Facebook

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a web app or web service that can monitor the status of Yahoo Mail, Twitter and Facebook to check if they are down?

In other words, I want to be able to see momentarily and easily when my favorite web services are down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Downrightnow](http://downrightnow.com/)** monitors the status of your favorite web services, combining user reports and official announcements to tell you when there's service trouble.

[image]